# Tenho que pegar um nome digitado pelo usuário e criar um arquivo com este nome...LING. C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){

    char nome_arq[20];
    printf("Digite o nome do arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s",&nome_arq);
    FILE *file;
    file=fopen("-------.txt","w");
    fprintf(file,"huahuahuahuauh");
    fclose(file);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendo o `#include <string.h>` você pode utilizar a função strcat(str1, str2) para concatenar 'strings', deixando sua lógica mais ou menos assim:

```
file=fopen(strcat(nome_arq, ".txt"),"w");
```